# Get products by a particular manufacturer

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute, product-collection, manufacturer

I want to display all the products which belongs to a particular manufacturer.

Here is my code:-

```
$manufacturerId = 2;
$attributeCode = 'manufacturer';
$products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, $manufacturerId);

echo $products->getItems();
```

It displays nothing. How can I get this??

Comment: it is issue  with attribute,Please  check attribute is used in Product listing(Goto manage attribute>select manufacture> ckd Used in Listing)

Comment: i set it to yes but still no change in frontend.

Comment: please tell me what you get when you either log or var_dump your $products variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `$products->getItems();` try looping through the collection.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    //do something with product
}
```

But I suggest adding some attributes to the collection. You might get only the id and sku (and a few other uninteresting attribute values) the way you are doing it.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') //instead of * you can use an array with the required attributes
    ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, $manufacturerId);
```

Comment: I have tried it also but its not working.

Comment: But are you sure there are products for that specific manufacturer?

Comment: yaa there are some products for that manufacturer.

Comment: Is the manufacturer attribute marked 'Use in product listing'? If not, try to set that flag to yes and reindex everything.

Comment: it is already set to yes.

Comment: Are you usung the default manufacturer field in Magento? Or you added a custom text attribute?

Answer (score 0):

- First crosscheck your set manufacturer id on the products that you
  want to fetch.
- After by viewing your code it seems you used echo, rather you should use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` for printing array.

  Otherwise the code seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need all products collection then you get it product list as per manufacture.
Try This

```
   $name = 'brand';
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

$specificbrand = array();
foreach ($attributeOptions as $_option)
{
    $productcollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter($name, $_option['value']);
    foreach ($productcollection as $_product)
    {
        if($_option['label'] == 'specificbrand')
        {
            $specificbrand[] = $_product->getSku();
        }
    }
} 

print_R($specificbrand);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to do the same -

```
$manufacturerId = 2;
$attributeCode = 'manufacturer';
$products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('eq' => $manufacturerId));
```

Then you just have to loop through and get details -

```
foreach($products as $_product){
echo $_product->getName();
}
```

Make sure the attribute is added in Attribute set.